# Can you use an op-amp like this to detect current?

Tags: operational-amplifier

For a model train track, I'd like a simple circuit which can detect current. In the past, I used an opto-coupler in combination with 2 diodes. A current flowing through these diodes would cause a voltage drop of 1.4 V over the opto-coupler. This was enough to steer the opto-coupler open. The 1.4 V voltage drop was a problem, because it lets trains make a noticeable jump in speed. So I am looking for a replacement.

There are other methods to detect current, but most of them are relative large circuits with too many components.

So I drew this experimental circuit. The idea is that a very small current flowing through a 0.2 Ω resistor, would create a voltage over the op-amp, causing it to drive the LED when this voltage is positive. I am aware that the voltage would be negative 50% of the time. But an Arduino can filter the signal further.

[image: op-amp schematic]

So my question is: Will this circuit work? Is the connection between the 0 V and 16 V supply needed? Or would it work without it as well?

Comment: So you just want to use the opamp as a comparator? Arduino filtering won't stop a negative voltage or overvoltage from frying the opamp. The resistors in combination with internal ESD diodes might save the opamp though.

Comment: Do you want to amplify the voltage to be able to sample it with and ADC or simply make a digital signal go high at a certain threshold?

Comment: I dont want an analog signal, just a digital signal. The idea is when the voltage on the + side is slightly higher it get's amplified to VCC level (5v in this case)

Comment: Take a look at something like the [Allegro ACS712](https://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/files/datasheets/acs712-datasheet.ashx) - it uses a hall-effect sensor to isolate from the AC, and gives you a voltage out which is proportional to current. It's not exactly what you want, but could be used ( if the price is right ), or could point you more in the right direction

Comment: It also depends on the opamp. You need a "rail to rail" opamp, or feed a regular one off +/-5V instead of 5V and GND.

Comment: 1)  What is the minimum current you want to detect?  2) What is the maximum current the circuit will see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems simple, but you should be concerned about some points:

- any intermittent contact in the rails could generate high voltage, caused by motor inductance, which I sincerely don't know how it would be managed in a scaled model train and its rails.
- depending of current needed by train’s motor, voltage drop in 0R2 might be too small (still ok) but might be above 0.4Vpeak, if any current exceeds 2A. In this case, an OpAmp as LM358, according to the datasheet, would withstand Input Voltages from -0.3V to +28V.

So in the above scenario, the input side of LM358 is NOT protected.

**Suggestions**:

**1 -** I would suggest adding in parallel to your 0R2 sensing resistor another 2 Schotkky diodes (as 1N5817, 18 or 19) in anti-parallel to limit the maximum voltage drop to +/- 0.3V (up to 1A) or +/- 0.6V (up to 5A for 100cycles > 1s).

**2 -** Then, using a voltage divider of R1= 10K (between 0R2 sensing and +input) and R2= 2K2 (between +input and Ground), would further limit Negative Voltages (< 0.3V) and Positive ones to *never* apply input voltage above Vsupply = 5V.

**3 -** Output LED will be powered in the “rectified” sensed AC. In case its flicker in the optocoupler might not be OK, adding almost any diode + electrolytic capacitor, between OpAmp and output resistor will solve that flicker. Oversizing the capacitor might even stretch the pulse duration, if also desired.

With such output, you could even drive the base of any medium power transistor as TIP31 to drive lamps, solenoids or relays directly (reminding to use a diode to absorb inductance’s voltage spike).

**Summary:**

I would give a try in your idea using an LM358, but protected by 2 diodes and a voltage divider. Any LED + resistor at the output will give you optical feedback of its functionality, where the output could then be used to further drive any desired load.

Answer (score 2):

That will work with a single-supply op-amp like LM358. The connection between 0V and 16VAC is necessary (or something like that). It would be best to add a resistor in series with the non-inverting input of the op-amp since the input doesn't like it when applied voltages go much below zero.

Note: because Vos of the op-amp can be positive or negative, you cannot predict the state of the output with no current (could be either high or low). You could either add circuitry, use an op-amp with Vos or trim, or detect changes in your firmware- it will go high and low at the VAC frequency.

Note that if your VAC is higher than mains frequency (for PWM, for example), the op-amp may not be able to keep up. The last time I had a model train, the controller looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unvtl.png) but I imagine things have moved on since then.